# Parsing through text file with javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a text file with multiple records each with a new line like below

```
username ="Test1" :[Jul 01 2012]
username ="Test2" :[Jul 03 2011]
username ="Test3" :[Jul 28 2011]
username ="Test4" :[Jul 12 2010]
```

How do I parse through this text with the above format and only store the data between the two  square brackets? [] so the result returned would look like this.

```
Jul 01 2012
Jul 03 2011
Jul 28 2011
Jul 12 2010
```

I would like to use JavaScript only to accomplish this task.

Thank you in advance for any support!

Comment: Please read this regular expression article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through each line, and parse out the data you want.  RegExes should work well here.

Let's say your string is in the variable `myText`:

```
var lines = myText.split("\n"),
    dates = [], tempVar;
for(var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++){
    tempVar = lines[i].match(/^.*:\[(\w{3} \d{2} \d{4})\]/);
    if(tempVar !== null){
        dates.push(tempVar[1]);
    }
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Uqaj9/

Comment: Quick question for you. How do I alter your line match  code .match(/^.*:\[(\w{3} \d{2} \d{4})\]/); so that lets say sometimes the data in the bracket could be like this format [Mar 16 2011:11:52:51 GMT]

Comment: @BaconJuice: You could just grab everything in the `[]` regardless of its format: `/^.*:\[(.*)\]/`

Comment: If you ever need a liver or kidney, let me know =)

Comment: @BaconJuice: Nah, I don't need anything like that.  I'll just take your 1st born, and we'll be even. :-P

Comment: I just got one final question! I tried playing with your code but I seem to get a wrong result. How do I change the result from "Jul 01 2012", "Jul 03 2011", "Jul 28 2011", "Jul 12 2010" to "Jul 01 2012" "Jul 03 2011" "Jul 28 2011" "Jul 12 2010" essentially removing the comma and replacing it with a line break instead.

Comment: @BaconJuice: `dates` is an array.  What are you doing with it?

Answer (score 1):

```javascript
function extractBetweenBrackets(str) {
  return str.split(/\n/).map(function(x) {
    if (x.match(/:\[(.*?)\]/)) { return RegExp.$1; }
  });
}

var str = 'username ="Test1" :[Jul 01 2012]\n'
        + 'username ="Test2" :[Jul 03 2011]\n'
        + 'username ="Test3" :[Jul 28 2011]\n'
        + 'username ="Test4" :[Jul 12 2010]';

extractBetweenBrackets(str);
// => ["Jul 01 2012", "Jul 03 2011", "Jul 28 2011", "Jul 12 2010"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: `/[a-z]+ \d{2} \d{4}(?=\]$)/gim`

```
[a-z]+    # multiple basic latin chars.
          # an empty space
\d{2}     # a 2 digit integer
          # an empty space
\d{4}     # a 4 digit integer
(?=\]$)   # followed by a closing square bracket and then an end-of-line
```

Flags:

- `g` is for global, makes it match as many as it can
- `i` is for case insensitive. This is for the first part
- `m` is for multiline, which makes the dollar sign match the end of line instead of end of string